# Speed up c++ unordered_map insert if hash is present?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

I've got an `std::unordered_map<Foo, int>` with an overwritten hash function for Foo. I also need hash(Foo) for other purposes, so I wonder if:

1. I can add a new Foo foo to the map with a present hash for foo,
   saving an unnecessary duplicate invocation of hash(foo)?
2. Alternatively, if I can add foo to the map and get the
   calculated hash, so I don't have to calculate it again separate to
   the insert operation?

Comment: You could just make an `unordered_map` using the hash type as key and pass a do nothing hasher (passes the hash through).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: that could work for me. What would be the most efficient way to define and pass a "do nothing" hasher to an unordered_map? Speed is critical here.

Comment: If you specialize `std::hash` for `Foo` you can make it save the hash in a member of `Foo`.

Comment: @Chris Since it's based on templates, a sufficiently simple hashing function, including one that just returns it's argument, is likely to get optimized out.

Comment: @super: that's not really an option here, as Foo can be modified during it's lifetime. I'd have to include to reset the hash each time the object gets modified, and I'm not sure what the performance trade-off would be.

Comment: @Chris To ellaborate on super's suggestion, you could consider using `std::pair<size_t, Foo>` as a key, and storing the hash in the first member of the pair. Then you could use a hasher that returns that member. Though it's not as light-weight as the other solution suggested, it has the benefit that you can still recover the `Foo` that was used as a key. Using `size_t` alone as a key means you can't recover that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Francois' suggestion, using a "do nothing" hash to spare an additional calculation would solve me problem. Here is what I came up with, any comments on speeding this up further would be appreciated.

```
struct DoNothing {
    std::size_t DoNothing::operator()(const std::size_t &key) {
        return key;
    }
};

std::unordered_map<std::size_t, Foo, DoNothing>
```